# How to replace the expression with evaluation result using Elisp interpreter?

Tags: eval, eval-expression

When I do bulk calculations in a scratch buffer, it is annoying to have to delete the actual expressions after they are evaluated (I want them to be deleted on evaluation).

Example:

```
(+ 2 2)
```

Pressing `C-u C-x C-e` gives:

```
(+ 2 2)4
```

What I want instead is only this (the expression has been removed):

```
4
```

Is there a command that I'm not aware of? I'm curious if there is an easy work around before I write something of my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possibilities that I am aware of.

1. In the package `crux` https://github.com/bbatsov/crux there is a function `crux-eval-and-replace` which does exactly what you are asking for. If you don't want to use the whole package you can just take this function.

```
(defun crux-eval-and-replace ()
  "Replace the preceding sexp with its value."
  (interactive)
  (let ((value (eval (elisp--preceding-sexp))))
    (backward-kill-sexp)
    (insert (format "%S" value))))
```

2. There is also the package `lispy`, see https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy that I like very much for editing lisp files. It has a function `lispy-eval-and-replace` which also does what you want but might be an overkill if you don't want to use the package.

Comment: it's funny, I pretty much collected my own crux over time. It could have saved me a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the expression in the minibuffer instead. Using `eval-expression` with the universal prefix argument inserts the result:

```
C-u M-: (+ 2 2) RET
```

Comment: Not related to the question. I do bulk calculation on thousands of lines in scratch buffer. Typing it out is not an option by any means.

Answer (score 0):

## Eval and Replace

The solution here is:

- No need to install any package.
- Can be tested directly (see below)
- Extension is possible with `Macros` (not mentioned here).

I found the best solution mentioned in the article here [Eval and Replace](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/06/21/eval-and-replace/)

```
(defun eval-and-replace ()
  "Replace the preceding sexp with its value."
  (interactive)
  (backward-kill-sexp)
  (condition-case nil
      (prin1 (eval (read (current-kill 0)))
             (current-buffer))
    (error (message "Invalid expression")
           (insert (current-kill 0)))))
```

### How to test

1. [Optional] Create a buffer like `playground.el` and put the code mentioned above (In case you want to keep this snippet for the next session).
2. Then highlight the code above, then `M-x: eval-region`
3. You will get the `eval-and-replace` loaded to your buffer.
4. Then simply test it on a `lisp` expression

- Open another file called test.el
- put lisp expression such as (+ 3 4)
- Put the cursor at the end of this express
- Run `M-x: eval-and-replace` function that we loaded.
  [image: demo]

Comment: Why do you say "no need to install any package"? Your recipe requires 3rd-party library `playground.el`, doesn't it? Maybe your first bullet should be removed?

Comment: @Drew-san,
I apologize for the unclarity of my previous post, I have adjusted. Indeed, you don't need any package, I mentioned these files (playground. el, test. el) for testing purposes only, I hope it is clear by now. Please let me know

Comment: Yep, clear now; thanks.